# Calculating intermediate extension on the stack of coherent sheaves of rank $1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, perverse-sheaves

Let $L$ be a line bundle of degree $d$ on a curve $X$ and let $x$ be a point of $X$. I want to describe the intermediate extension of the constant sheaf from the stack of line bundles of degree $d$ to the point given by the coherent sheaf $L(-x) \oplus O_x$ of rank $1$ and degree $d$ with determinant $L$. In order to do this, can I simply calculate the intermediate extension of the constant sheaf from $Ext^1(O_x, L(-x)) \setminus \{0\}$ to the vector space $Ext^1(O_x, L(-x))$? I.e. does $Ext^1(O_x, L(-x))$ form an atlas for the neighborhood of the point $L(-x) \oplus O_x$ in the stack of coherent sheaves  of rank $1$ and degree $d$ with determinant $L$?

Comment: Just curious- why did you take Yellow Pig as a name.  What does that have to do with mathematics.

Comment: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/01/25/easter-eggs-and-yellow-pigs/     https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/fun/yellow-pig-day